# Printing an XML file contains unique chars shows tree black diamonds

Tags: java, xml, maven, unicode, jar

I have a maven project compressed into an executable jar.

This jar is including an XML file that contains unique chars as: '度', '行'

While my maven program reads and prints this XML file, it prints the unique chars as three black
diamonds.

This is the code to read and print the XML file from the jar:

```
input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource);
String xml = IOUtils.toString(input);
AutomationLogger.getLog().debug(xml);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure where you're displaying that is capable of showing those characters?

Comment: yes, i tried to print these chars without the XML and it has worked @g00se

Comment: Can you please attach (or link to) the xml file?

Comment: The single-argument form of IOUtils.toString [is deprecated for good reason](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString-java.io.InputStream-).